# Running of ConTeXt along with MiKTeX 2.9 windows8 64bit

Tags: context

MikTeX 2.9 is running very well. However, I installed ConTeXt as instructed in the separate drive and specified path. When I tested in the command line I get the following error

> C:>context --version E:\context\tex\texmf-win64\bin\mtxrun.lua:14222:
>   C stack overflow

What have I to do to run conTeXt in the same system?

Comment: How did you install ConTeXT? via miktex, texlive, or standalone/minimals?

Comment: standalone via command line after placing the unzipped file in a drive e:

Comment: Did you run: `E:\context\tex\setuptex.bat` before running `context --version`?

Comment: yes. Even then I got the same error message

Comment: I don't use Windows. The best idea may be to post to the context mailing list. There are many Windows users of ConTeXt (include Hans Hagen, the developer of ConTeXt), who may be able to figure out why this is happening and how to avoid it.